# Postgresql plsh installation

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgresql8.4 running on fedora machine , I have to use this function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION callSQLScript(scriptPath text) 
RETURNS void AS $$
    #!/bin/sh
    plsql -f scriptPath
$$ LANGUAGE plsh;
```

for this I have to install plsh but while installing plsh it is giving error while executing make after psql -d DBNAME -f PREFIX/share/pgplsh/createlang_pgplsh.sql

```
/bin/sh: line 0: .: pgplsh.la: file not found
```

Taken installation reference from [plsh](http://plsh.projects.postgresql.org/)

Please Help me getting rid out of it.

Comment: Fedora *what*? 17? Something older?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue:

https://github.com/petere/plsh/issues/1

so you might want to grab the latest pl/sh. Of course, the latest version might not build with a server as old as 8.4.

Comment: I am using 1.3 latest version of plsh but this problem is still comming.

Comment: @SatishSharma Does 1.2 build? Or git master?